# Variables in route group prefixes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, variables, routes, laravel, laravel-4

Given the below routes it will respond to

> http://example.com/game/stats/123
>   http://example.com/game/stats/game/123
>   http://example.com/game/stats/reviewer/123

What I want to know is, how can I make it respond to

> http://example.com/game/123/stats
>   http://example.com/game/123/stats/game
>   http://example.com/game/123/stats/reviewer

I tried doing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game/{game}'], function($game){
```

But that fails with "Missing argument 1 for {closure}()"

Note that there are four other groups apart from stats but I have omitted them for this example for brevity.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'stats'], function(){
        Route::get('/{game}', ['as' => 'game.stats', function ($game) {
            return View::make('competitions.game.allstats');
        }]);
        Route::get('game/{game}', ['as' => 'game.stats.game', function ($game) {
            return View::make('competitions.game.gamestats');
        }]);
        Route::get('reviewer/{game}', ['as' => 'game.stats.reviewer', function ($game) {
            return View::make('competitions.game.reviewstats');
        }]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I notice some of your route parameters is prefixed with '$' and some are not.

Comment: Whoops, type, but it makes no difference as the parameter names only matter if you are using route binding, which I am not presently so it's only the order that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try this code see if it's what you want. Here the second group route it's just the `{gameId}`and then you have the `stats` group which wraps all the other routes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game'], function(){
      Route::group(['prefix' => '{gameId}'], function(){
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'stats'], function(){
          Route::get('/', ['as' => 'game.stats', function ($game) {
              return View::make('competitions.game.allstats');
          }]);
          Route::get('game', ['as' => 'game.stats.game', function ($game) {
             return View::make('competitions.game.gamestats');
          }]);
          Route::get('reviewer', ['as' => 'game.stats.reviewer', function ($game) {
             return View::make('competitions.game.reviewstats');
          }]);
        });
      });
    });
```

And then in your views you can call them by the route name and pass the `gameId` to the route;

```
{{ link_to_route('game.stats','All Stats',123) }}  // game/123/stats/
{{ link_to_route('game.stats.game','Game Stats',123) }} // game/123/stats/game
{{ link_to_route('game.stats.reviewer','Review Stats',123) }} // game/123/stats/reviewer
```

Hope this helps and solves your problem.

**EDIT**

I just checked It should work also with `Route::group(['prefix' => 'game/{game}'` as you have tried but just make sure to pass the `game` argument when creating the route like stated above. If you have more variables to pass you can pass an array to the function.

```
{{ link_to_route('game.stats','All Stats',['game' => '123','someOtherVar' => '456']) }}
```

Comment: AH! That's my issue, I was expecting that since when you put the variables in a route definition you need to add the variable to the route closure signature that you would need to do the same on the route group closures.